# Collpase classes like we collapse methods in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, editor, text-editor

I want to collapse whole class in eclipse,currently it is only allowing to collapse methods.

Please find the screen shot below:

[image]

Here you can see only methods are collapsed not the class Streams.

Is there any way or plugin to achieve this as IntelliJ is already providing this feature.

Comment: By default, you can fold/collapse inner types but not types on file level. Folding on file level would hide everything but the Javadoc of the type, right?

Comment: Folding is configured in the Preferences in 'Java > Editor > Folding', folding the top level class is not supported.